# How to register dynamique URL Handler for Spring WebSocket with @EnableWebSocket configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

Suppose that I have a WebSocket on the url:

wss://hostname:port/myapp/websocket

I have a Spring Configuration with an handler:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public MySocketHandler mySocketHandler() {
        return new MySocketHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(mySocketHandler(), "/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

}
```

All fine, it works.

But how to implement a dynamique URL?
What I have to do if I have something like:

url1: wss://hostname:port/myapp/websocket/call01

url2: wss://hostname:port/myapp/websocket/call02

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-annotations it should be the same with manual handler.

Comment: Thanks. However this is for Controller, not for a Configuration

Comment: Yes, check if the ant matchers are supported from "Configuration"